# Inserir na tabela da base de dados com o segundo formulário

Tags: php

Tenho este menu:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Produtos de Higiene</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#produto_1">Novo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_2">Entrada</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Depois tenho estes dois formulários:

```
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
        <div id="success_messages" class="hide">sucessso</div>
        <div id="error_message" class="hide">erro</div>
</form>
</section> 


<section class="hide-section" id="produto_2"> 
<form name="form1" id="form1" class="form-validate" id="feedback_form"> 
    <div class="campo">
         <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Entrada de Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
    </div>      
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Data Entrada">Data Entrada</label></strong>
            <input id="DataEntrada" type="date" name="DataEntrada" required="" style="width:180px" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Produto">Produto</label></strong>
        <select id="first_dd" name="Produto" style="width:250px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.ProdHigieneteste WHERE Ativo = 1 ORDER BY DescricaoProd ASC"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['IDProd'].'"> '.$ln['DescricaoProd'].'</option>'; 
                    $valencia[$ln['IDProd']]=array('DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid'],'DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid']); 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select>
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong>
        <select id="second_dd" name="Unid" style="width:150px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php
                foreach ($valencia as $key => $value) { 
                    echo '<option data-id="'.$key.'" value="'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'">'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'</option>'; 
                }
            ?> 
        </select><br> 
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Quantidade">Quantidade</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" style="width:80px" required="" size="40">
        <strong><label for="Preço">Preço</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" style="width:100px" value="0.00">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
        <div id="success_messages" class="hide">sucessso</div>
        <div id="error_message" class="hide">erro</div>
    </form>
</section>
```

tenho este script para enviar os dados para a página onde tem o código php para 
inserir na tabela:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        }, 
                    error: function(data){
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        },
                    complete: function()
                    { 
                         $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                    } 
                });

            });
 });
</script>
```

Depois tenho a página onde tenho o código php para inserir:
Código 1º formulário:

```
<?php

$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';

if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
   echo json_encode("true");
} else {
    echo json_encode("false");
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Código 2º formulário:

```
<?php

$data = isset($_POST["DataEntrada"]) ? $_POST["DataEntrada"] : '';
$produto = isset($_POST["Produto"]) ? $_POST["Produto"] : '';  
$unidade = isset($_POST["Unid"]) ? $_POST["Unid"] : '';   
$quantidade = isset($_POST["Quantidade"]) ? $_POST["Quantidade"] : '';
$preco = isset($_POST["Preco"]) ? $_POST["Preco"] : ''; 

if (!empty($data) && !empty($produto) && !empty($unidade) && !empty($quantidade) && !empty($preco)) {  
   echo json_encode("true");
} else {
    echo json_encode("false");
}

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO regEntradahigieneteste (DataEntrada,Produto,Unid,Quantidade,Preco) 
VALUES ('$data','$produto','$unidade','$quantidade','$preco')";

if ($conn->query($sql2)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}

$sql3 = "UPDATE StockHigieneteste SET Quantidade = Quantidade +" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockHigieneteste.IDProd =" . $produto;

 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

O problema que tenho, é que quando faço registo no primeiro formulário funciona tudo bem, insere na tabela e limpa o formulário, mas quando tento fazer registo no segundo formulário não insere na tabela nem limpa o formulário, e faz o registo nas tabelas do primeiro formulário e em branco.

Comment: seus forms não tem nenhuma action?

Comment: @MatheusReis Não precisa, porque tem o `ajax` para enviar os dados para a página onde tem o php, tem na pergunta essa parte do código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ajax()

Primeiramente o `ajax()` precisa enviar uma informação para distinguir no `PHP` qual ação vc quer tomar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".btn_contact").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("section").attr("id");
        var serialize = $("#"+id+" form").serialize();
        serialize += "&type="+id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./inserir",
            data: serialize,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
            }, 
            error: function(data)
                {
                    $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                },
            complete: function()
                { 
                    $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                } 
        });
    });
});
```

- `var id = $(this).closest("section").attr("id");` pega o id da `section` do formulário que será enviado
- `var serialize = $("#"+id+" form").serialize();` serializa o formulário
- `serialize += "&type="+id;` aqui ele adiciona um novo campo à `var serialize` que é o mesmo `id` da `section`, ele quem vai te ajudar a separar as ações no `PHP`

### PHP

Agora o `PHP` tem um identificador único para você conseguir separar as ações, que é o `$_POST['type']`:

**$_POST['type']=='produto_1':**

```
if($_POST['type']=='produto_1'):
    $name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
    $unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
       echo json_encode("true");
    } else {
        echo json_encode("false");
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
    VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
    if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
       // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
    } else {
       // get the error, throw a message...
    }

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
    VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

    if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
        //Count total number of rows
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    } else {
        // get the error, throw a message...
    }
    $conn->close();
endif;
```

**$_POST['type']=='produto_2':**

```
if($_POST['type']=='produto_2'):
    $data = isset($_POST["DataEntrada"]) ? $_POST["DataEntrada"] : '';
    $produto = isset($_POST["Produto"]) ? $_POST["Produto"] : '';  
    $unidade = isset($_POST["Unid"]) ? $_POST["Unid"] : '';   
    $quantidade = isset($_POST["Quantidade"]) ? $_POST["Quantidade"] : '';
    $preco = isset($_POST["Preco"]) ? $_POST["Preco"] : ''; 

    if (!empty($data) && !empty($produto) && !empty($unidade) && !empty($quantidade) && !empty($preco)) {  
       echo json_encode("true");
    } else {
        echo json_encode("false");
    }

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO regEntradahigieneteste (DataEntrada,Produto,Unid,Quantidade,Preco) 
    VALUES ('$data','$produto','$unidade','$quantidade','$preco')";

    if ($conn->query($sql2)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
       // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
    } else {
       // get the error, throw a message...
    }

    $sql3 = "UPDATE StockHigieneteste SET Quantidade = Quantidade +" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockHigieneteste.IDProd =" . $produto;

     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

    if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
        //Count total number of rows
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    } else {
        // get the error, throw a message...
    }       
    $conn->close();
endif;
```

Não é a pratica mais adequada, pois acredito que possa ser feito de uma maneira com menos cara de gambiarra, mas como seu sistema já funciona, e você quer solucionar o problema, isso resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Ambos os seus forms tem um mesmo `id`, e essa é uma péssima prática. Seu form está inserindo dados vazios porque, quando você dá um submit, ele pega os dados do primeiro form, que estão vazios, e insere no banco de dados.

Experimente preencher os dois forms, e veja quais dados serão inseridos na tabela. Certamente serão os do primeiro form, que tem o primeiro `id` `feedback_form`. Altere os `id`'s, para que eles sejam diferentes, e altere também a lógica, para que o submit deles seja "independente".

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vi você detecta o click no **.btn_contact**, um botão que está nas duas forms, até aí nada de errado. Mas na hora de puxar os dados da form você só puxa de um ID **#feedback_form**. Então sempre vai puxar os dados de um formulário só.

Alterando um pouco o seu código eu fiz com que o script buscasse a form por conta própria para sempre pegar aquela em que o **.btn_contact** está dentro:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".btn_contact").click(function () {
            var myForm=$(this).closest("form");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./inserir",
                data: myForm.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                        $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                    }, 
                error: function(data){
                        $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                    },
                complete: function()
                { 
                     myForm.find('input').val(''); //clear text
                } 
            });

        });
});
</script>
```

Creio que isso deve resolver, testa lá e me diz como foi!

Comment: Um dúvida @Iniciante, os dois formulários devem enviar para **"./inserir"** mesmo?

Comment: sim, é onde tenho o código php

Comment: Testei o código (tirando a parte do registro PHP) e ele está passando os dados para o AJAX então agora deve ser algo no PHP mesmo, ele chega a dar algum erro ao registrar? Talvez algum erro no SQL?

Comment: @Iniciante Lembre-se que a responsabilidade para fazer funcionar é sua, não de quem responde, então comentários como "*não funcionou*" não trazem nenhum benefício para a discussão ou para a comunidade. Ao invés de apenas copiar/colar a resposta e executar, busque entender o que foi descrito na resposta, reconheça qual foi o seu erro e busque corrigi-lo com as dicas dadas.

Comment: @Henrique Pauli, no php não recebo nenhum erro, o problema é que ao inserir com o segundo formulário ele utiliza sempre o código de inserção do primeiro formulário. Ao fazer registo com o segundo formulário, devia ignorar o primeiro código de inserção e inserir com o segundo...eu penso que o problema está no lado do php, porque envia os dados, mas não sei como resolver

Comment: @Iniciante, tente criar um input hidden com o nome **"acao"** (por exemplo) nos dois formulários, no primeiro você define o valor de **"acao"** como "inserir" e no outro como "entrada". No seu código PHP você verifica, se **$_POST['acao']=="inserir"** então use o código do inserir, caso contrário use o outro código PHP.